# Ruby not printing variable in output

Tags: ruby, printing

I am working on a project that computes an output, and then prints the type of output along with the output number itself.

```
class H_con < OH_pH 
    #calculate [H+]
    def calculate()
       k_pH = self.know_ph?
       k_oh = self.know_oh?

       #using pH to calculate
       if k_pH == true
           pH = self.get_pH
           @h = 10 ** (-1 * pH)
       #using [OH-] to calculate
       elsif k_oh == true
           oh = self.get_oh
           @h = Float((1 * (10**-14))/(oh))
       end
   end

   def out()
       self.put "[H+] concentration", @h
   end
end
```

`self.put` looks like this

```
def put(type, answer)
    puts "#{type} is #{answer}"
end
```

`self.return` is included in the class `Calc`, and the class that `H_con` is a subclass of is a subclass of `Calc`.

When I run the program, everything up until this point seems to work fine (there's lots of code not shown that gets input, etc.), but the print from the command line looks like this `[H+] concentration is` with nothing after it where the variable should print. I am not quite sure what's wrong, I looked up some syntactical things, and tried to change it around a bit, but it appears to not be affected by a comma, or quotation marks.

Can anyone tell what's wrong?

Update: I did not know not to use `return` as a method name, so to improve the code I changed it to `put`. However, this did not alter my output.

Comment: Isn't `return` a keyword?

Comment: don't use `return` as function name. It is reserved keyword.

Comment: @YuHao @Esse I just tried changing the method name `return` to `put` and it didn't change the output.

Comment: I wouldn't use `return` as a method name just for good practice, but since it is being called and executing code that is not the problem.

Comment: I'm guessing `@h` is nil. It never gets set in the `k_pH == true` block, so if `self.know_ph?` evaluates to true, you will never set `@h`, and that would explain the message you're seeing.

Comment: @AndrewSchwartz I just went in and changed that, and still no output. That was definitely an error though, thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: Try using brackets, sometimes it gets confused by the commas
`self.put("[H+] concentration", @h)`

Comment: try `p answer` (instead of `puts`) in your `self.put` method. That will tell you exactly what is being passed in. If you are using a ruby console, you might be using a stale class definition of `H_con` if you did not reload the console.

Comment: @Abdul-RahmanAhmad the use of spaces instead of parens here in the method call should be totally supported and I'm pretty sure is not the issue either. It's only an issue when you have other grouping that the ruby interpreter doesn't parse as you intended, e.g. with an `or` operator or a `x ? y : z` ternary operator.

Comment: @AndrewSchwartz `p answer` did return the correct value, so the program appears to be computing and assigning it correctly.

Comment: @AndrewSchwartz However, it's still not being included in the regular output

Comment: It appears to be fixed, however I don't know what fixed it. Thank you all very much for your help!